# Solve Differential Equation with Boundary Conditions (lengthy equation)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, parameters

I have a lengthy equation to be substitute into a differential equation. I used DSolve to generate the output. However, it took me more than 3 hours and it still running. The DE is the convective-diffusion equation which is

`1/r del /del r (r del f1s/ del r) - a1 = 0`

and the boundary condition is
`r=k` when `del f1s/ del r =0`

so the input is:

```
a1 = -(810165067720210957064125/25546163167349695028752149) - 
     0.00395833 (-0.5 + r) (1.02817 + 
        3.98107/(5.36839*10^11/r - 1.*10^12 r)^(1/20) + 
        2./((1.27718 - 0.666667 r - 0.333333 r^2)/(1. + r))^(1/20) + 
        3./((3.05377 - 0.888889 r - 0.111111 r^2)/(4. + r))^(1/20) + 
        3.01772/(-((1. (-0.675531 + 0.125 r + r^2))/(0.0625 + r)))^(
        1/20) + 3.03794/(-((1. (-0.867019 + 0.285714 r + r^2))/(
          0.142857 + r)))^(1/20) + 
        2.04096/(-((1. (-1.14539 + 0.5 r + r^2))/(0.25 + r)))^(1/20) + 
        3.08948/(-((1. (-1.57936 + 0.8 r + r^2))/(0.4 + r)))^(1/20) + 
        3.12414/(-((1. (-2.32712 + 1.25 r + r^2))/(0.625 + r)))^(1/20) + 
        3.23431/(-((1. (-7.80849 + 3.5 r + r^2))/(1.75 + r)))^(1/20)) + 
     0.125 (-0.5 + r) (0.196614 + 
        1.32702*10^-12 (5.36839*10^11/r - 1.*10^12 r)^(19/20) + 
        0.666667 ((1.27718 - 0.666667 r - 0.333333 r^2)/(1. + r))^(
         19/20) + ((3.05377 - 0.888889 r - 0.111111 r^2)/(4. + r))^(
        19/20) + 
        0.894139 (-((1. (-0.675531 + 0.125 r + r^2))/(0.0625 + r)))^(
         19/20) + 
        0.787613 (-((1. (-0.867019 + 0.285714 r + r^2))/(0.142857 + r)))^(
         19/20) + 
        0.453547 (-((1. (-1.14539 + 0.5 r + r^2))/(0.25 + r)))^(19/20) + 
        0.572125 (-((1. (-1.57936 + 0.8 r + r^2))/(0.4 + r)))^(19/20) + 
        0.462835 (-((1. (-2.32712 + 1.25 r + r^2))/(0.625 + r)))^(
         19/20) + 
        0.239579 (-((1. (-7.80849 + 3.5 r + r^2))/(1.75 + r)))^(19/20))


TRY = DSolve[{1/r D[r f1s'[r], r] - a1 == 0, f1s'[k] == 0}, f1s, r, GeneratedParameters -> S]
```

I'm stuck and I don't know what else should I do. I tried to do manually by integrating the equation but it's kinda haywire. Could anyone help me out with this coding. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: You wrote `DSolve[{1/r D[r f1s'[r], r] - a1 == 0, f1s'[k] == 0}`  but I see no `k` anywhere in your input.  I suggest you try numerical DSolve on this. Since this is second order ode, you'd need additional BC to do numerical.

Comment: `k` is used for the boundary condition, as I stated  `f1s'[k] == 0` . Did you mean try to use `NDSolve` ? and could you clarify as you said additional BC is needed to solve second order ODE , I don't get what you mean. The DE is in first order ode.

Comment: I mean you do not have an actual value for $k$. Your ode is not first order. It is second order. You typed `D[r f1s'[r], r]` . A derivative of a derivative gives second derivative. So to use numerical dsolve, you'd need an additional BC. I do not think this can be solved analytically. Your `a1` is too complicated.  Yes, numerical dsolve, is `NDSolve`. You can try that. But you need an actual value for $k$ and need another BC specified.

Comment: I'm overlooked at the the equation, yes it is second order ode. I have 2 BC actually which are `f1s'[0.5] == 0`  (replaces `k` with `0.5`) and `f1s'[1] == 0` . Does it look somewhat like this  `NDSolve[{1/r D[r f1s'[r], r] - a1 == 0, f1s'[0.5] == 0, f1s'[1] == 0}, f1s, r]`. However, it appeared like this (NDSolve:: Unable to resolve the conditions derived from the given boundary conditions. It is possible there is no solution for the given boundary value problem.)